# What is the difference between Equals and = in LINQ?

Tags: vb.net, linq

What is the difference between **Equals** and **=** in LINQ?

```
Dim list As List(Of Foo) = (From a As Foo In FooList _
Join b As Bar In BarList _
On a.Something = b.Something _
Select a).ToList()
```

versus

```
Dim list As List(Of Foo) = (From a As Foo In FooList _
Join b As Bar In BarList _
On a.Something Equals b.Something _
Select a).ToList()
```

Comment: I think you mean the difference between == and Equals.

Comment: Vb.net doesn't use ==.  I know, it annoys me too.

Comment: Ah, I skimmed over it and didn't even realize it was vb, please excuse me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [The Moth](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/equals-Versus.aspx) who quoted Matt Warren

> "The reason C# has the word ‘equals’
>   instead of the ‘==’ operator was to
>   make it clear that the ‘on’ clause
>   needs you to supply two separate
>   expressions that are compared for
>   equality not a single predicate
>   expression. The from-join pattern maps
>   to the Enumerable.Join() standard
>   query operator that specifies two
>   separate delegates that are used to
>   compute values that can then be
>   compared. It needs them as separate
>   delegates in order to build a lookup
>   table with one and probe into the
>   lookup table with the other. A full
>   query processor like SQL is free to
>   examine a single predicate expression
>   and choose how it is going to process
>   it. Yet, to make LINQ operate similar
>   to SQL would require that the join
>   condition be always specified as an
>   expression tree, a significant
>   overhead for the simple in-memory
>   object case."

### EDIT

Later in the article.

UPDATE: Vladimir Sadov from the Visual Basic team told me that VB also uses Equals for pretty much the same reasons.

Comment: This question was about VB.net, not C#

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the second version will compile and the first one will not.  The VB query syntax requires that the contextual keyword `Equals` be used when comparing items in a LINQ query in this fashion.

How this operator works is defined in section 11.21.5 of the VB language spec

- Both expressions must be classified as a value.
- Both expressions must reference at least one range variable.
- The range variable declared in the join query operator must be referenced by one of the expressions, and that expression must not reference any other range variables.
- If the types of the two expressions are not the exact same type, then

  - If the equality operator is defined for the two types, both expressions are implicitly convertible to it, and it is not Object, then convert both expressions to that type.
  - Otherwise, if there is a dominant type that both expressions can be implicitly converted to, then convert both expressions to that type.
  - Otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.